# I don't understand how this line works: "System.out.println("\nCard: " + Deck.get(number).getValue() + " of " + Deck.get(number).getSuit() );"

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, chaining, chain

The code below is a code shared with me by someone who I can't reach right now. I'm still new to array listing, method chaining, and pretty much to coding as well. I tried converting the "Deck.get(number).getValue()" into "Deck.getValue()" and some other variations but the code seems to fail everytime I do so. Can someone explain that specific line and why it only works when chained?

P.S.

- Apologies to everyone who finds this post too basic or tedious due to lack of clarity. This is my first time posting, and I am what my username suggests.

import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.*;

public class Card {

```
private String suit;
private String value;


public static void draw(){

    int number = (int) (Math.random() * Deck.size());
    System.out.println("\nCard: " + Deck.get(number).getValue() + " of " + Deck.get(number).getSuit() );
    Deck.remove(number);
}

public static void count(){

    System.out.println("\nCards left in the Deck: " + Deck.size());

}

public Card(String suit, String value){
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
}

static ArrayList<Card> Deck = new ArrayList<Card>(52);

public String getSuit(){
    return suit;
}

public String getValue(){
    return value;
}

public void setSuit(String suit){
    this.suit = suit;
}

public void setValue(String value){
    this.value = value;
}


public static void main (String[] args){

    String[] Suits = {"Clubs", "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds"};
    String[] Values = {"A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int a = 0; a < 13; a++){
            Card Card = new Card(Suits[i], Values[a]);
            Deck.add(Card);
        }
    }
    int choice;
    do{
        cls();

        System.out.println(" -----------");
        System.out.println("|1. Draw    |");
        System.out.println("|2. Count   |");
        System.out.println("|3. Exit    |");
        System.out.println(" -----------");

        System.out.println("Choose an Action: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        choice = sc.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1)
            {
                draw();
            }
        else if (choice == 2)
            {
                count();
            }
        
    }while(choice!=3);
}
```

}

Comment: I would have though that many Cards were held in a Deck, not the other way around.

But anyway to answer your question `Card` is a ArrayList.  An ArrayList is a collection of similar Objects e.g. a classroom of students, a library of books etc.  When you call `get` you are returning one Object (Deck) and then you are asking for its value.

Going back to the example of a Library of Books, you would not want the title of the Library, when you want the title of a book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cards` is the name of your `ArrayList<Deck>`, meaning there's a list of "Decks" (which are really just individual cards). If you try to do something like `Cards.getValue()`, the code doesn't really know which card in the list you're referring to. The extra step to the chain `Cards.get(index)` gets a specific card at the specified position in the list, which you can then call `getValue()` on to get the value of that card.

Your code is a bit confusing because it doesn't really accurately represent how a deck of cards works. To make it clearer, the list currently named `Cards` should be called `Deck` (because a deck of cards is essentially a list of multiple cards), and your `Deck` class should be named `Card`, since it takes a single suit and value, which is unique to every card.

That way, you'd have something like `List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();`. Naming the variables properly can really help understand what's going on in the code.

Comment: How does the getValue() receive the index number from the get(index)? When chaining, does the previous value received automatically get sent to the next method? Because the value needs to enter the parenthesis right? For Example: ".getValue(Card)"

Again, I'm sorry if my questions sound really dumb. I am still learning the basics.

Comment: Every time you call a method, that call returns the method's return value. In this case, when you call `get()` on a list, it returns the object at the specified position in the list. So, when you use `get()` on a list of type `Card`, you'll get a `Card` object. You can then call any method that the object has, like `getValue()`. Think of `String val = Deck.get(0).getValue()` as a shorter way of writing these two lines: `Card c = Deck.get(0);` (which gets the first card in the deck) and `String val = c.getValue()` (which gets the value of that card).

Comment: This is the answer I have been looking for. It makes perfect sense to me now, Thanks a lot!